# How to name a DataFrame in Spark to make the DAG diagram easier to read?

Tags: apache-spark, debugging

In Spark, the DAG diagram can get quite complicated after a few joins, for example:

[image]

Is there a way to make it more understandable by, first, naming Spark datasets, and seconde, tagging each stage with the dataset that it computes (or help to compute) so that we could trace the stages back to the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can name the rdd as

```
yourrdd.setName(“ABCD”)
```

Comment: do we have the equivalence of that for Dataset and Dataframe?

Comment: there won’t be any equivalent for dataframe as in spark even if you write code in dataframe, everything will be converted to rdd ultimately by spark. So in spark UI you can only see the details w.r.t to rdd

Comment: OK, that makes things harder than it should be... :-(